# How to download heavier packages first in packman parallel mode?

Tags: arch-linux, upgrade, pacman

You can enable parallel mode by uncommenting the `ParallelDownloads = 5` line in `/etc/pacman.conf`.

My question is, can I change the order by which packages are downloaded? Can I queue the heavier packages first?

Comment: guess that needs a change in pacman itself, so maybe you shoud post a feature request for it... PS: Good idea, but What are you saving on average? with  a good internet connection a few seconds?

Comment: I'll admit I don't know how much I save. I just remember that several times the linux update was both the heaviest thing downloaded AND the last to start download. I'm think there should be some mathematical way to calculate the download savings, but I have no idea how to do it.

Comment: I think a more useful case would be trying unstable/failing connections in parallel to reliable connections...

Answer (score 0):

As you are specifying the `ParallelDownloads` to `5`, then the all 5 downloads will run in parallel weather you sort them by size that doesn't even make any sense, because all 5 files will be downloaded parallelly.

Comment: that they are sorted by size DOES matter. If I leave a heavy file to be loaded last, it would lengthen the entire process. If I put heavy files to be downloaded first, the total time will be shorter.